# Error with BaseGameUtils.resolveConnectionFailure

Tags: android-studio, google-play-games

I'm creating an app using the Google Play Game Services. I am doing the login but I'm having troubles with the Google Examples. Anyone knows something about this error?

[image: error]

Comment: Check the app and BaseGameUtils dependencies in the Project Structure. Add play.services and support libraries as dependency.

Answer (score 0):

Discussed in [GoogleApiClient - Constant Summary](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient#constant-summary)

> If a required authenticated API fails to connect, the entire GoogleApiClient will fail to connect and a failed `ConnectionResult` will be delivered to `onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult)`.

To further help you troubleshoot issues, [Troubleshooting Issues in Your Android Game](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/troubleshooting#unable_to_sign_in) might help.